# What is causing an error showed in the Google Play Console pre-launch report?

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

I launched my app in the alpha channel, and my Google Play Console pre-launch report details page shows an error occurred on Android 12 (SDK 31).
The stack trace that show me is:

```
ANR in com.google.android.apps.safetyhub;PID: 11778;Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE flg=0x30 pkg=com.google.android.apps.safetyhub cmp=com.google.android.apps.safetyhub/com.google.apps.tiktok.experiments.phenotype.ConfigurationUpdatedReceiver_Receiver (has extras) };
```

I don't see the name of my package anywhere.

Can you help me to understand what is causing the error?

Comment: if you check the details of the ANR you're getting, there must be a screen recording video attached, which will be sufficient to understand the error or crash. It might be a crash caused by your app, but not the case all the time.

Comment: @TheHeist I tried in several physical devices and have no errors, so could be the screen reecording video the cause.

Comment: We have the exact same issue with Android 13 (SDK 33) ... not using any video features in our app at all . @Mike087 could you share how did you solve this at the end?

Comment: Any solution please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using those packages of the ANR it is warning you about, it is likely a bug in the Google Play Console testing platform and/or simulated device. This is especially the case an error only appears on one device. It tests on numerous different emulated devices, so if it's just happening on one, it's probably just a one-off glitch that's unrelated. Good news is you don't need to pass the pre-launch report in order to release, so you can ignore it!

In any case, you should double check the full logcat. Click 'show more' then click the -> to the right of the device, then click download full log cat. If it doesn't seem like your app initiated any calls, it's probably just a background crash that is unrelated to your app and you can disregard it.

Comment: We can not ignore these stability issue, this will halt the launching the app in play store, any other solution please

Comment: Can you describe more to why it will halt launching? I had a similar error and I was still able to release it. Are you sure you are not getting errors elsewhere? (i.e. policy errors etc). I have a "Errors found. Fix before releasing to production." error message under pre-launch report overview, but the app is still released to production regardless of this error.